# Como fazer edições valerem durante debug?

Tags: python, debug, pycharm

Quando estou depurando um código no Pycharm (Shift+F9) e faço alguma alteração, ela não é reconhecida durante a mesma sessão de debug. Sou obrigado a reiniciar o debug novamente para as alterações serem reconhecidas.

Existe alguma forma de que o Pycharm reconheça as alterações DURANTE o debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seria legal você colocar um exemplo de quais variáveis está tentando alterar. 
Mas de qualquer forma, se você estiver tentando mudar variáveis locais em uma função que está debugando, isso não é possível por conta de como o Python é implementado:

Os mecanismos internos da própria linguagem que permitem a depuração e outros, sempre atualizam as variáveis locais de forma "read only": o depurador ou qualquer função chamada pode ver as variáveis locais acessando o atributo `f_locals` do frame de execução da função que está sendo inspecionada.

No entanto, apesar de até a versão 3.7, o f_locals conter um dicionário normalzinho, que permite alteração dos valores, esses valores **não** são copiados de volta para as variáveis locais da função quando ela realmente é executada. Isso até hoje era mais ou menos um "detalhe de implementação" do CPython, indicado em algumas partes da documentação - mas está sendo formalizado como parte da especificação da linguagem na [PEP 558](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0558/).

Em resumo: nem o debugger do pycharm, nem nenhum outro debugger, nem nenhuma funcionalidade que não viole as especificações da linguagem para fazer "mágica" em valores de uma função que chama outras (explicitamente, ou de forma implicita, como é o caso no funcionamento de depuradores), pode alterar o valor de uma variável local.

**No entanto**, se você está precisando disso para agilizar seu fluxo de trabalho, existe um *workaround*: os objetos que estão associados aos nomes nas variáveis locais não podem ser *trocados*, mas podem ser *alterados*. Isso é, se sua o conteúdo da sua variável for um número ou uma string, não há nada que possa ser feito. Mas se seu conteúdo for uma lista, dicionário, ou outro objeto mutável, esse objeto pode ser mudado do contexto dos depuradores.

Então, vamos supor que sua função tenha uma variável `id`  que você gostaria de poder mudar interativamente de dentro do debugger - você pode (talvez temporariamente) mudar o seu código para que os valores que te interessam estejam dentro de uma lista:

Em vez de:

```
def minha_func(id):
   ...
   consulta_ao_banco(id)
   ...
```

Você pode fazer:

```
def minha_func(id):
   id = [id]
   ...
   # neste trecho do código, o conteúdo da lista em 'id' pode 
   # ser alterado de dentro do debugger
   ...
   consulta_ao_banco(id[0])
   ...
```